# Python: изменить кодек и частоту аудиофайла

Tags: python, аудио

Доброй ночи. Как можно изменить кодек и частоту аудиофайла? Это прям необходимо, потому что одна программа странно зависит от этих настроек. Для создания использую следующий код:

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("test1.wav")  
sound = sound + AudioSegment.from_mp3("test2.wav")  
sound.export("test3.wav", format="wav")
```

Answer (score 0):

Частота меняется через [resample()](https://audiosegment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/audiosegment.html#audiosegment.AudioSegment.resample), если использовать модуль audiosegment, который добавляет дополнительные функции к pydub. Или функцией `set_frame_rate` через pydub.

Кодек выставляется через параметр `codec` функции export.

Comment: sound.export("test3.wav", format="wav", codec="pcm_s16le".)     

Выдает следующую ошибку: https://prnt.sc/ABc3WWNdMABo